# Filter key/value array by value in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have this **sample data**:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "marcadores": [
      { "k": "G", "v": "00" },
      { "k": "1", "v": "A" },  
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "marcadores": [
      { "k": "1", "v": "A" },
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "marcadores": [
      { "k": "G", "v": "03" },
      { "k": "P", "v": "55" }
    ]
  }
]
```

I would like to filter those documents with these critera:

- `marcadores.k: "G"` and `marcadores.v: { $ne: "00" }` (`$elemMatch`). In the example, `"id": 3` meets this criteria

or

- document has no `marcadores.k: "G"`. In the example, `"id": 2` meets this criteria.

**Expected output**:

```
[
  {
    "id": 2,
    "marcadores": [
      { "k": "1", "v": "A" },
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "marcadores": [
      { "k": "G", "v": "03" },
      { "k": "P", "v": "55" }
    ]
  }
]
```

What's the best/cleanest way to solve this query?

You can use this [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/EGY1sfyjVTW).

Comment: By filter you mean you want to get them in the result or out of the result?

Comment: Thanks  @nimrodserok, let me add expected output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `find` we can use `$not` with `$elemMatch`:

```
db.collection.find(
  {marcadores: {$not: {$elemMatch: {"k": "G", "v": "00"}}}}
)
```

See how it works on the [playground example - find](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Qzk4NCXQA-f)

Comment: Looks good! At least in terms of output data... Let me understand a little bit the query and I set the answer as correct. I upvote in the meantime...

Comment: Thank you @nimrodserok, works nice I will use it. It's a pitty get forced to create new fields to filter the query, but sometimes there is no alternative with mongodb.

Comment: You are right. After doing I saw we can do the same using find :)

Comment: Can't you do the same approach (using the `$elemMatch`) for aggregation?  See [this playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/x-H8OcQeSk_).

Comment: I was not aware of that :) Thanks @user20042973!